# Inverse Laplace transform of square term plus constant under square root in denominator.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How to find inverse laplace transform of:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}$$

Discussion:

Further:

$$L^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}})=F(t)$$

Ideas that came to me were:

1. To use laplace transform of erf($\sqrt{t}$), but that clearly has the limitation of not having $s^2$.
2. Convolute F(t) so that sin(x) comes on RHS (but that will lead again to an integral equation if we differentiate it twice)
3. Differentiate $s^{-1}tan^{-1}(s^{-1})=L[Si(t)]$ to introduce $s^{2}+1$, but i see that it would get complicated.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the binomial series:
$$ (1+x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k}x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty = \frac{(-1)^k (2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}x^k.$$
This gives
$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}} 
= \frac{1}{s} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{s^2}}} 
= \frac{1}{s} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}\frac{1}{s^{2k}}. $$
Take the inverse Laplace transform for every term:
$$ f(t)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^{2k+1}}\right\} 
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k t^{2k}}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}.$$
This is the power series of the Bessel function $J_0$ of order 0.

Comment: What if s^(-2) is greater than 1, that is s lies between 1 and -1 (if s is real) ? Then you cannot expand as you have. But the solution is good and thanks for that.

Comment: I believe one can expand this as it is written here, no? The convergence radius of the series is infinite, so this expression holds for all real $s$. It is a different story when you do the same calculation for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}$, for instance. (Fun fact: in this case the inverse Laplace transform is the modified Bessel function $I_0$.)

Comment: I have got complete clarification! Thanks!

Comment: @Ernie060 To be precise, the Laplace transform of $I_0$ is $1/\sqrt {s^2 - 1}$. The inverse transform won't exist for the principal branch of $1/\sqrt {1 - s^2}$ and will be off by a factor of $i$ for the continuous branch.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, indeed! The denominator should indeed be $\sqrt{s^2-1}$. Thanks for noting this.